# How to Decodable value with response data

Tags: json, swift, decoding

PortfolioModel

```
public struct PortfolioModel : Decodable {

    let symbols_requested: Int
    let symbols_returned: Int
    let data: [Portfolio]
}
struct Portfolio : Decodable {

    let stockValue : StockValue
    let todaysLowHigh : HighLowValue
    let fiftyTwoWeekLowHigh : HighLowValue
    let priceBandLowHigh : HighLowValue
    let stockPriceValue : StockPriceValue
    let stockStatistics : StockStatistics

    struct StockValue: Decodable {

        let stockName: String?
        let stockCurrentPrice: String?
        let stockChangeValue : String?
        let stockVolume : String?
        let stockDateValue : String?
    }

    struct HighLowValue: Decodable {

        let minimumValue : String?
        let maximumValue : String?
        let currentValue : String?
    }

    struct StockPriceValue: Decodable {

        let bidPriceValue : String?
        let bidQtyValue : String?
        let offerPriceValue : String?
        let offerOtyValue : String?
        let openPriceValue : String?
    }

    struct  StockStatistics : Decodable{

        let stockMarketCapValue : String?
        let stockDividendValue : String?
        let stockDivYield : String?
        let stockfaceValue :String?
        let stockMarketLot : String?
        let stockIndustryPE : String?

        let stockEPSTTM  : StandColidate
        let stockPC : StandColidate
        let stockPE : StandColidate
        let stockPriceBook : StandColidate
        let stockBookValue : StandColidate

        let stockDeliverables : String?
    }

    struct StandColidate : Decodable{

        let standalone : String?
        let consolidate: String?
    }
}
```

WebServicesClientServer

```
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
            do {

                let result = try decoder.decode(PortfolioModel.self, from: response.data!)
                self.portfolio = result.data
                print(result.data)
                completion(self.portfolio)

                return
            }
                catch {
                    MKProgress.hide()
                    print("Decoding error:", error)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                MKProgress.hide()
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
```

Server Response

```
{
    "symbols_requested": 1,
    "symbols_returned": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "symbol": "AAPL",
            "name": "Apple Inc.",
            "currency": "USD",
            "price": "196.85",
            "price_open": "196.45",
            "day_high": "197.10",
            "day_low": "195.93",
            "52_week_high": "233.47",
            "52_week_low": "142.00",
            "day_change": "1.16",
            "change_pct": "0.59",
            "close_yesterday": "195.69",
            "market_cap": "926316741610",
            "volume": "8909408",
            "volume_avg": "28596757",
            "shares": "4715280000",
            "stock_exchange_long": "NASDAQ Stock Exchange",
            "stock_exchange_short": "NASDAQ",
            "timezone": "EDT",
            "timezone_name": "America/New_York",
            "gmt_offset": "-14400",
            "last_trade_time": "2019-04-05 12:28:19"
        }
    ]
}
```

I got catch block error message

> Decoding error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "stockValue", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"stockValue\", intValue: nil) (\"stockValue\").", underlyingError: nil))

I know its wrong way of decoding! All all String values into single `struct Portfolio` But can I achieve it with following ProtfolioModel?

Comment: By the way, it makes no sense to use `responseJSON` if you are decoding JSON by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: There is no key `stockValue` in the array for key `data`. There is no dictionary representing a struct in that array anyway.

These two structs match the JSON, quickly created on [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift)

```
public struct PortfolioModel : Decodable {

    let symbolsRequested: Int
    let symbolsReturned: Int
    let data: [Portfolio]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbolsRequested = "symbols_requested"
        case symbolsReturned = "symbols_returned"
        case data = "data"
    }
}

struct Portfolio: Codable {
    let symbol, name, currency, price, priceOpen, dayHigh, dayLow: String
    let the52_WeekHigh, the52_WeekLow, dayChange, changePct, closeYesterday, marketCap: String
    let volume, volumeAvg, shares, stockExchangeLong, stockExchangeShort, timezone: String
    let timezoneName, gmtOffset, lastTradeTime: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbol = "symbol", name = "name", currency = "currency"
        case price = "price", priceOpen = "price_open", dayHigh = "day_high"
        case dayLow = "day_low", the52_WeekHigh = "52_week_high", the52_WeekLow = "52_week_low"
        case dayChange = "day_change", changePct = "change_pct", closeYesterday = "close_yesterday"
        case marketCap = "market_cap", volume = "volume", volumeAvg = "volume_avg", shares = "shares"
        case stockExchangeLong = "stock_exchange_long", stockExchangeShort = "stock_exchange_short"
        case timezone = "timezone", timezoneName = "timezone_name", gmtOffset = "gmt_offset", lastTradeTime = "last_trade_time"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Still need to verify this but, this was my solution for handling JSON.

Had this same issue for decoding JWT.

The steps are as followed:

1. Convert the data to to UTF8

```swift
let data = response.data(using: .utf8)!
```

2. Serialize JSON Object

```
guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else { return }
```

3. Use Struct to interpret the data (modify as needed)

```
        struct Json {
            let data: Array?

            init(json: [String: Any]) {
                data = json["data"] as? Array ?? []
            }
        }
```

4. Get the data as an object key

```
let dataArray = Json(json: json)
let symbol = dataArray.data.symbol ?? ""
```

All Together:

```
            do {
                let data = response.data(using: .utf8)!
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else { return }
                let dataArray = Json(json: json)
                let symbol = dataArray.data.symbol ?? ""
            } catch {
                let message = "Failed to extract token from json object"
                // Your error message handle
                // logMessage(messageText: message)
                return
            }
```

Comment: No need to convert the `response`. `response.data` **is** the `Data` representation. And don't suggest `.mutableContainers`. It's pointless in Swift and it's pointless anyway if you assign the result to an immutable constant. And this way to decode JSON into a struct is outdated.

Comment: Good to hear. Again, a bit of a newb to Swift, but trying to see where I can help, but still learning :)

Follow up question, is it required to account for all fields for the JSON structure in your example with enumeration or can you just omit certain fields?

Comment: If you specify `CodingKeys` you have to include **all** keys which have corresponding struct members.

Comment: Is there any way around that then, because what if the payload data structure changes from the API?

Comment: No, if the API data structure changes you have to change the Swift structs. You have to change the way to parse the data anyway regardless which parsing API you are going to use.

Comment: Thanks @vadian appreciate the clarification.